# What does it mean to "parade wind its way through ...(a location)"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, definition

What does it mean to "parade wind its way through ...(a location)"?

Also, What is another usage for "to wind its way through" in general?

Comment: In general, it would be helpful if you provide some details, like a complete sentence, paragraph, story, source, your own research, etc. Failure to do so might attract down votes and close votes. Please see [_Details, Please_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: For a good synonym here, use your English dictionary and look up the verb _to meander._

Comment: Related: [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/52052/6700), especially the sentence "Route Napoleon **snakes through** the Provincial landscape." That question is about the use of verbs for motion to describe static shapes, and this question is about a verb describing the shape of a motion, but the concept is similar (as is the photograph).

Comment: Please use the **[edit]** link under your question to tell us where you saw a sentence containing the phrase "parade wind its way through". This has the potential to be a useful question, but we need more [**Details, Please.**](https://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming this came from a sentence like "... the parade winding...". In this context, a parade is like a public celebration, and "winding" means to travel through (usually around many bends) a place. So "The parade winding through America" would mean that the parade is travelling through America.

Answer (score 1):

"Parade its way through ______" means "moving through in a grandiose manner." Basically that whoever or whatever is moving through wherever, is doing so with no attempt to go unnoticed, rather that they want to be noticed, and for the movement to be a grand affair. This is sometimes a matter of ego, such as a mighty warrior who thinks very highly of themself, stomping and yelling valiantly as they walk through a town street.

"Winding its way through" indicates much turning, and could be called "weaving". This could happen in a dense forest, or through the alleys and back streets of a city, where in either case a straight path is not likely.

EDIT: I misread the first sentence. I didn't realize it was a parade (noun) winding through _______. As such, my first paragraph may not apply as much as I thought, but I will leave it unedited anyway, as it may still be useful.

Comment: Not enough reputation yet, but "winding its way" or "wound its way" does not (at least in this part of the US) have any connotation of grandiosity.  Speaking from experience, a Mardi Gras parade "winds its way" because it goes up and down various streets, or is taking an indirect route to get from one point to another to maximize the actual length of the route.

Comment: My first paragraph is for "Parade its way through", omitting winding. I also have an edit on my answer explaining that I misread the original question.