# he was coaxed a safe distance away -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Tortoise pursues man in ‘slowest chase ever’](http://www.grindtv.com/outdoor/nature/post/tortoise-pursues-man-in-slowest-chase-ever/)

> Once Rose **was coaxed a safe distance away**, the tortoise turned and beat a hasty retreat back to the female. Well, it wandered back as quickly as it could. Presumably, the female was still waiting in the bushes.

I'm not sure how to understand that part, specifically the expression *was coaxed away*.

Comment: It’s not an expression. Did you look up [coax](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/coax)?

Comment: There’s an elided “to” that might be causing trouble. It’s sort of saying “was coaxed [to] a safe distance”.

Comment: *Rose was **persuaded** [to move to a different position that was] a safe distance away*. I think the general sense of the [implicit] words there should be obvious (possibly after using a dictionary if necessary to establish that ***coax = persuade***).

Comment: This is a common pattern with verbs like beckon, summon, coax, invite, order, motion. They take a direct object and a verb-complement:  *The driver was motioned off to the side.*  *She was coaxed a safe distance away.*

Comment: The question seems on-topic. As Tyler notes, there is ellipsis at work here. More challenging, I suspect, *coax away* could look like a phrasal verb, and definitions of *away* are numerous enough that I think many an ELL might carry some trouble through some dictionary consultations and appropriately ask for a simple reformulation here.

Comment: I think the phrase in question means approximately черепаха отогнал Роуз, except coax is much gentler than отогнать, and (I think) Russian doesn't have a construction analogous to _away_ after a verb to indicate where the subject moved to, though Russian does use prefixes on verbs of motion to indicate that. Cookie Monster, does that sound like the source of the confusion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In "coaxed a safe distance away", the phrase "a safe distance away" refers to where Rose *went* as a result of being coaxed.

### English verbs of motion

The pattern that you see in the phrase "coax away" is very common in English verbs that describe motion, especially of Germanic origin. Many languages, like the Romance languages, don't have this pattern (and it doesn't work with many English verbs that come from Latin).

The pattern is: a verb of motion typically indicates the manner of motion but not the path or direction. The path or direction is indicated by a special word following the verb. Many words that work as direction words, though not all, can serve as prepositions in other contexts. Here are some more examples:

> Rose **ran away**. (Rose ran to some place away from where she started.)
>
> Rose **walked inside**. (Rose walked from outside some enclosure to a point inside the enclosure.)
>
> Rose **fled upstairs**. (Rose fled from the ground floor and went up the stairs.)
>
> Rose **flew north**.
>
> Rose **turned around**.
>
> Rose **came home**.
>
> Rose **wandered back**.
>
> Rose **jumped ahead**.

This works passively, too:

> Rose was **led away**. (Someone led Rose to a place away from where she started.)
>
> Rose was **coaxed inside**. (Someone gently persuaded Rose to enter some enclosure.)
>
> Rose was **driven upstairs**. (Someone or something forced Rose to go up the stairs against her will.)

These direction words can form the nucleus of more-complicated phrases. For example:

> Rose was **coaxed ten feet outside the front door of the bank**. (Rose was inside the bank, and then someone coaxed her to **come outside** the front door of the bank, and continue moving until she was ten feet away from the door.)

And of course, the same constructions work metaphorically:

> Rose was **coaxed out of her lunch money**. (Rose was coaxed to give her lunch money to someone else.)

### It usually doesn’t work with verbs from Latin

This pattern of "coaxed away" often doesn't work with verbs of motion that come from Latin:*

> Rose **entered inside**. (This means that Rose entered (something) *while* she was already inside (some enclosure), not that the act of entering put Rose inside.)
>
> Rose **exited downstairs**. (This means that Rose exited the building when she was downstairs, not that the act of exiting moved her downstairs. But "moved downstairs" does follow the Germanic pattern.)
>
> "Hey, Rose, <strike>**ascend inside**! **Ascend up** the ladder!</strike>" yelled Johnny from the treehouse. (That doesn't sound like English. The native English verb is *climb*: "climb inside" or "climb up". With *ascend,* you use a direct object: "ascend the ladder".)

Notice that these last three verbs denote the path or direction of motion, not its manner.

If you're curious to learn more about this, look up "[satellite-framing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_framing)".

---

* <sub>It's not a rule, of course. "Turn" is from Latin (actually Greek via Latin), and partly follows this pattern. "Turn" sort of denotes a path, and sort of denotes a manner of motion.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

*To coax* means *to successfully entice to move*, the immediate image that comes to mind as an example is trying to get a scared dog or cat that doesn't know you to come to you by saying "come here" in a friendly way.

*Rose was coaxed a safe distance away* means Rose was successfully enticed to move a safe distance away.