# A question about how native speakers learn prepositions

Tags: prepositions

There are several prepositions which can be placed after an adjective. So I wonder which one should be chosen. Are they the same, or are there some nuances among them? Given a single sentence without context, how can a native speaker understand the sentence correctly? I want to know the process of understanding the different usages.

For example,

> disappointed adj ~ (about/at sth); ~ (in/with sb/sth);sad or
>   dissatisfied because sb has failed, some desired event has not
>   happened, etc
>
> - be disappointed **about/at** sb's failure
> - I was disappointed **with** his performance.
> - I'm disappointed **in** you: I expected you to win.

As you can see, after the adjective "disappointed", you can use different prepositions,like "about" "at" "with" "in". Are they the same? Which element can decide the usage of preposition?

How do the native speakers learn the preposition at the beginning?

Comment: There's no way you can **guess** it perfectly. For that, you need to be a born native! And, the question you just put here has been my question since years... and yeah, not just for the prepositions, even for pronunciations of various words. They pronounce correctly though they read it for the very first time, I struggle even if I've read it before! +1 and starred! :)

Comment: Many of my American friends in a public US high school had never taken grammar  classes so nobody ever told them what a preposition even was. So I am not sure that (many) English-speaking students have properly learned this.

Comment: We native speakers often can*not* know the meaning of individual sentences. This is why we very often ask a learner to provide more context. As for prepositions, teachers can only present example uses, many example uses. But getting a firm grasp on the many uses and distinctions in meaning comes only by *exposure to the language* in natural contexts. It can take years. But the more you listen and read, the more you'll learn. (That is also how natives learn more advanced uses.) I'm learning Italian and prepositions are a pain in the arse.

Answer (score 11):

The very short answer: they do it just the same way that you learned all that difficult grammar in your own mother tongue.

---

Slightly longer:

How does anyone learn their native language?

Well, according to linguists, they do not.

The process of getting to know how to speak your mother tongue is called **acquisition**, not learning.

Learning is what other people do when they learn the language as a second (or third, etc) language. They learn the rules, the grammar, and they try to apply them.

Young children subconsciously analyse the words and phrases they hear around them, and they build up a "grammar" in their head, as well as a dictionary, a thesaurus, enormous lists of collocations, etc. They don't actually sit down to study, they just absorb and analyse.

So a native speaker *knows* that he should say *he works* instead of *he work*, and even when he encounters a verb that he has never seen before, he *knows* the third person singular will get an *-s* in the simple present.

The amazing thing is that he *knows* that, even if maybe he *does not know anything* about grammar. Even if he doesn't know what a "verb" is, what "simple present is", or "third person singular". Even if he has never seen a grammar book, he will be able to correctly say *he (new verb)s*.

Just look around you at any young kids. You may think that your mother tongue is easy, because even little children speak it very well. But it's not. It's as easy or difficult as English is, and those kids (and you, when you were little) are doing what children everywhere do: they build up an understanding of the grammar of their mother tongue without even realizing it.

Ask a five-year old why he just conjugated that verb correctly, ask him in which grammar book he saw the rules for that, and at best you will get a blank stare.

*You* had discovered an enormous amount of grammar by the age of three, just like any kid, in any language.

---

This question reminds me of this old joke:

> I am so glad I was not born in China, because I don't speak a word of Chinese!

Comment: Except many foreign/second language methodologies concentrate on exposure and acquisition rather than the study of grammar. And, for adults, their ability to analyze the language according to grammar gives them a leg-up over kids learning their first language.

Comment: @pazzo sure, modern teaching methods try to use acquisition instead of learning, exactly because it works more intuitively. Whether adults have an advantage because they analyze grammar remains to be seen - just look at all the questions here on ELL that stem from things going wrong in that analysis, like over-applying rules, or using over-simplified rules instead of intuitive (native-speaker) patterns. Kids become fluent in their native language much faster than (most!) adults do in a new language, so it seems the kids have the advantage :)

Comment: Yeah, when I said ***a** leg-up*, I was referring to this one ability only over kids, not to adults' overall situation. Second, yes it's true this ability may not apply to many 2nd/FLL,precisely because they are not being taught using acquisition methods. This is probably true of 90% of the learners here. People seem to equate learning a FL with learning chemistry, which is not how it works, as we both agree.

Comment: So what I mean is that learners who are aware of the acquisition  process but who can analyze the grammar also, as an **aid**, not a methodology, knowledge of *this* strategy can give adults a strategy that most kids do not have. **99% of questions** here could be answered by: get more exposure to the target language and you will come to realize how it works. But people (a) want to see language-acquisition as they do learning chemistry, (b) want answers now, when waiting will do much to resolve their questions.

Comment: @pazzo indeed, we do agree :) But let's keep finding other ways to answer questions here, as it would get quite boring answering 98% of them in the same way :)

Comment: I hear of so many weird claims and perverse use of language from linguists. So learning your native language isn't learning, because you don't memorize explicitly stated rules and consciously apply them? So learning to walk, learning to ride a bicycle, and learning to write computer programs aren't learning, either? I think the question is a good one and merits an answer, regardless of what you call the process.

Comment: Are you sure that kids learn (or whatever) their native language faster than adults? I've heard that a lot, but it seems to me that an adult, aided by a teacher and even some explicit talk about grammar and rhythm, typically learns at least 100x faster than an infant, when measured in terms of exposure and practice time. In calendar time, adults usually go more slowly, since they're more distracted, but a typical adult can outperform a native 4yo in less than four years of study and immersion in an L2. But I don't know for sure. Have you read anything about this?

Comment: @BenKovitz "Language acquisition by adults is language learning--a deliberate, painstaking, intellectual process that rarely, if ever, results in the total native fluency acquired so naturally by any small child, regardless of intellectual ability or personal motivation. The deficiency is particularly evident at the phonetic level, and adults who learn second languages usually speak them with some recognizable non-native accent. Thus, language acquisition by children and language learning by adults are strikingly different phenomena."

Comment: http://emedia.leeward.hawaii.edu/hurley/Ling102web/mod5_Llearning/5mod5.4_L2.htm  of course you can always just Google *kids first language acquisition* or similar

Comment: @pazzo I thinking finding good info about how fast adults vs. children learn from the same exposure is not trivial; the information I've come across so far seems equivocal. (I don't consider redefining "learn" an answer.) That page does mention "Adults have less time and opportunity to learn and practice L2. It takes well over a year to accumulate as much L2 experience as a young child gets from learning L1 in a month." If an adult learns 10x as much from 1/12 the exposure, that would be learning 120x as fast—which would contradict the claim that kids learn faster. But who knows?

Comment: @pazzo I think we're all in agreement, though, that "memorize facts _about_ the language and regurgitate them on exams" is a pretty ineffective way of learning (or whatever word we want to use for getting good at something). I don't even think it works very well for chemistry. You have to get your hands dirty in the lab. I especially liked your remark that "99% of questions here could be answered by: get more exposure to the target language and you will come to realize how it works." I suspect that a lot of questions here are really "help me pass this exam".

Comment: @BenKovitz I think you are the only one who brought up *speed* as an issue. (Well, okay, oerkelens did, but not me). For kids newborn to age 4 or 5 they learn/acquire  naturally, without explicit instruction, at a pace that goes along with other developmental things such as walking, so that by the time they enter primary school they have a firm grasp on speaking and the underlying grammar. Also, remember adults *already* have a first language or two upon which to map the new language they are learning, so I don't see speed comparison all that helpful here.

Comment: @pazzo oerkelens brought it up in the 2nd comment. I understand its relevance here to be the idea that natives have some quasi-magical, "critical period" ability or authority, which adult non-natives can't have. All we can do, on this theory, is stand in awe of the children, call their learning process by a special jargon word, and not even try to tell an ESL learner something useful and specific about how natives learn English prepositions.

Comment: @pazzo Anyway, I know it's very hard to give a good answer to this question. I'll post an attempt right now, which should be easy to criticize. Maybe that will give someone an idea for a better one, or maybe oerkelens will get some ideas for how to edit this one, based on his or her unusual knowledge and experience.

Comment: @BenKovitz I don't think it's hard to post an answer to this question. Which is why I could post a [comment giving a summary answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59124/a-question-about-how-native-speakers-learn-prepositions/59133?noredirect=1#comment112940_59124).

Comment: @pazzo Your summary answer certainly nails the most important factors: learning _in_ natural contexts, and vast exposure to examples. I'm hoping to see an answer that says something more specific about natives' understanding of prepositions, though. I just posted my answer; that ought to give a clearer idea of what I mean.

Answer (score 10):

Native speakers learn English prepositions from context and by actually communicating. This gives them a few important advantages over someone trying to learn prepositions from dictionaries.

### Prepositions in phrasal verbs

The biggest advantage of learning prepositions from context is that you don't expect them to have a meaning out of context. Prepositions in English often work as parts of familiar *phrases,* not as words like "replace", which have a pretty clear meaning that can be understood out of context.

The fact that English prepositions work as parts of phrases is a major stumbling block for people learning English as a second language. If your native language doesn't work this way, it can be hard to believe until someone points it out, so here are a couple illustrations:

- The phrase "**disappointed in *somebody***" is itself a unit of meaning. You can think of it almost like a word. The word "in" in that phrase shares very little common meaning with "in" in "[Someone's **in** the kitchen with Dinah](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcPk1-UjHKQ)." That's the primary meaning of "in": containment. The phrase "disappointed in" echoes the primary meaning just a little bit, but the phrase has a meaning of its own. You can't understand the phrase by looking up the dictionary definitions of "disappointed" and "in" and trying to combine them.
- The phrase "**fitting in**" is itself a unit of meaning. Here's an example: "When I was in high school, I had a hard time **fitting in**." The phrase means getting people to accept you within a social group. Notice that "in" does not introduce a prepositional phrase. There's no noun serving as the object of "fitting in". The word "in" follows the verb and changes its meaning. This is very common in English verbs.

Sometimes people call those phrases "phrasal verbs" to distinguish them from verbs whose meaning is entirely contained in one word. But really, there is no precise boundary between phrasal verbs and single-word verbs. Native speakers don't think of phrasal verbs as clearly separate from single-word verbs. Native speakers easily combine prepositions with single-word verbs in new ways, *by analogy with* familiar combinations, which they know from experience that other people are familiar with. [This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/58136/6700) is about "**toggle in**", a phrase not found in dictionaries, but which a native speaker—in context—easily understands by analogy with the familiar phrase "**type in**". Out of context, though, a native speaker probably couldn't figure out what "toggle in" means.

So, the only way to really understand English prepositions is to become familiar with a large number of these phrases. Then you can vary them or make new phrases by analogy with them in new situations. That's how native speakers learn them and use them. A dictionary definition can only vaguely point to the vast range of ways that a preposition seems to fit into phrases. It can't communicate the preposition's meaning in all those phrases—because the preposition really doesn't have an independent meaning of its own most of the time. I posted some more about learning the phrasal aspect of English under [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/55225/6700).

### The rhythm of prepositions

An advantage of learning by talking is that you pick up the rhythm of the language. The rhythm of English is important for many reasons, one of which is that prepositions have different ways of fitting into a sentence depending on their grammatical role.

When a preposition introduces a prepositional phrase, as in "Someone's **in** the kitchen **with** Dinah," it's normally quick and unstressed and it works rhythmically like an upbeat in music. The preposition's rhythm leads to the next stressed syllable. If there's an article between the preposition and the noun, it gets even less emphasis.

But when a preposition doesn't lead to a noun, as in "fitting **in**", it gets emphasis: it's stressed and said for a longer time. If you say "FIT<sub>ting in</sub>" (giving weak emphasis to the last two syllables, as if "in" were introducing a prepositional phrase), people won't understand you.

Regarding nuance or why people choose one preposition over another, sometimes the main reason for a choice is just to make a good, understandable rhythm. Most books and classes that teach English do not teach anything about sentence rhythm, and I've never seen a word about it in a dictionary. Prepositions have a rhythmic role that native speakers learn mostly by *imitating* other native speakers. Of course, you can do that, too. You can focus on the rhythm of sentences in recordings, and imitate not just the words but the rhythm and intonation, too.

### Prepositions as direction words

As a native, something else you learn from English prepositions is a certain way of thinking about direction, motion, and shapes, and how to fit that information into a sentence. Specifically, a preposition after a verb of motion usually indicates the direction or destination of that motion, as in "Dinah went **in**." Many languages don't work this way; in the Romance languages, you would use syntax like "Dinah entered". So, as natives master English prepositions, many verbs of motion feel incomplete without a preposition to finish the thought. More information about this is [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/53153/6700), including verbs that *don't* work with prepositions in this way.

Another habit of thought that native English speakers have is equating a shape with a path of motion. For example, someone might say that a pipe **loops over** a wooden beam. Since prepositions usually indicate direction, they play an important role here. See [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/52052/6700) for some illustrations of verbs of motion used this way. Note the use of the preposition "around".

As a non-native, you can explicitly focus on how prepositions add direction to verbs of motion for a while. That will help you acquire some of the same habits of thought that natives acquire in childhood. Many phrasal verbs draw upon prepositions' role as providing a direction to complete a thought, in order to make useful analogies with motion or shape.

---

I've never read anything specifically about how native English speakers learn prepositions. The above are just educated guesses, mostly based on common confusions of foreigners and common ways that natives fail to understand a foreigner's confusion when answering a question (suggesting that the native's habit of thought is so deeply ingrained that they don't attend to it consciously).

Comment: You haven't been around for quite a time! Welcome back! :)

Answer (score 0):

No one will teach you the proper use of prepositions, especially not videos which hardly reach lowest school level. The use of prepositions is a very wide and a rather difficult area of language. Grammars don't cover this sector as it can be treated only in form of a dictionary. Grammars cover only the basics of prep usage. For a learner that should be enough. When you have reached the level of reading books, novels and other reading matter, you have to study prep problems on your own in the dictionary, no one will come and open the dictionary for you. The main problems with preps are preps with a lot of uses, such as of to for on in at and words which can have several preps after them. You have to study each case which is a problem for you separately. And it is helpful to make notes in a systematic way. There are problems e  ven dictionaries have not registered. Then you have to consult several dictionaries, British ones and American ones and you can ask on forums. But there isn't a trick as some learners think.  Sure use of preps is connected with hard work.